# why murano-test-runner connecte to keystone?

Tags: unit-testing, openstack

I add some unit tests for my package "kubernetes-cluster" follow Tomcat Package(see: https://github.com/openstack/murano-apps/blob/master/Tomcat/package/Classes/TomcatTest.yaml).

and then, run it with command(without --config-file,--os-auth-url, without murano.conf in path /etc/murano/):

```
murano-test-runner -v io.murano.apps.docker.kubernetes.KuryrCluster io.murano.test.KuryrClusterTest -l /my-packages and core-library/local/path
```

I got the error message:

```
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 | 2017-03-16 07:42:50.773 1697 ERROR murano.cmd.test_runner [-] Command failed: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 |   File "/home/jenkins/workspace/murano-programming-language-unit-test/.tox/murano-test-runner/lib/python2.7/site-packages/murano/cmd/test_runner.py", line 374, in main
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 |     exit_code = test_runner.run_tests()
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 |   File "/home/jenkins/workspace/murano-programming-language-unit-test/.tox/murano-test-runner/lib/python2.7/site-packages/murano/cmd/test_runner.py", line 213, in run_tests
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 |     ks_opts = self._validate_keystone_opts(self.args)
2017-03-16 07:39:49.978 |   File "/home/jenkins/workspace/murano-programming-language-unit-test/.tox/murano-test-runner/lib/python2.7/site-packages/murano/cmd/test_runner.py", line 195, in _validate_keystone_opts
2017-03-16 07:39:49.979 |     ks_opts[param] = ks_opts[param].replace('v2.0', 'v3')
2017-03-16 07:39:49.979 | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
2017-03-16 07:39:49.979 | 
2017-03-16 07:39:49.979 | Command failed: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I just want to check my unit tests write in muranoPL right or not, like pep8 or py27.
Can I run `tox -e murano-test-runner` like `tox -e py27` without connect to keystone server and neutron server? If can not , why? if I can, how? mock keystoneclient and neutronclient? or other ways?
some one can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mock:

`keystoneclient.v3.Client(and deal with auth_uri.replace('v2.0', 'v3') AttributeError Exception)
murano.engine.system.net_explorer.NetworkExplorer._get_client`

then murano-test-runner can run without config-opts os-* or config-file